# How to retrieve youtube videos associated with a subscription

Tags: objective-c, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

it's not clear from the [youtube data api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/) how to immediately display videos associated with a user subscription. For example in the youtube iOS client (version 10.31.11670), suppose i click on my *aarmin van buuren* subscription.. it will immediately show a list of videos under it (there is also a *videos* tab):

[image]

[image]

[image]

From the youtube data api.. I can do the following:

### 1. retrieve a user's subscriptions

using youtube [subscription api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) for a user  we get (amongst other things):

```
 {

   "kind": "youtube#subscription",
   "etag": "\"sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/JMhno_Wae-hxWVRKTkIpLhQybR4\"",
   "id": "jdBPZ2FSEH2Q9kFmXaAiv0HFD6yePlK2vhWiM86Jn5s",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-08-25T14:22:33.000Z",
    "title": "Moretoki",
    "description": "Here's my channel for random vlogs, skits, challenges, tags, collabs and other shenanigans.\n\nSend me stuff if you want:\nMotoki Maxted\nP.O. Box 257\nWauseon, Ohio 43567",
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#channel",
     "channelId": "UCPvyOQD9hxY8433PN9QalIg"
    },
    "channelId": "UCuYVSPi09ZCcjxzUEVa4Geg",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-0yxR0ez3Cts/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/wyjHkDa5MUg/s88-c-k-no/photo.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-0yxR0ez3Cts/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/wyjHkDa5MUg/s240-c-k-no/photo.jpg"
     }
    }
   },
```

so from the above we have channelID **UCPvyOQD9hxY8433PN9QalIg**

### 2. retrieve channels corresponding to a subscription

entering it into the [playlists.list api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list)

> channelId string
>   This value indicates that the API should only return the specified channel's playlists.

we get

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistListResponse",
 "etag": "\"sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/uGzAgLKA3x8AEd-nxyJ5lhZcxSs\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#playlist",
   "etag": "\"sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/eVp7hvk1O_j60JIxT7FuF4W4NKs\"",
   "id": "PLwwBPMOKYX3PfjOwByTLJMeMKE48ybU2m",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2014-07-09T15:31:56.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCPvyOQD9hxY8433PN9QalIg",
    "title": "VidCon 2014",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
```

so we have a playlistID **PLwwBPMOKYX3PfjOwByTLJMeMKE48ybU2m**

### 3. Retrieve playlist item corresponding to a channel

entering it into a [playlistItems.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) api we get

```
"items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/CzkXHmWO1vOcEsZzjsWrqhuMFbc\"",
   "id": "PLJrD1EGFW0r-lGr4519_DEUl6_eusNtNEcusKszRfKl4",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2014-07-09T15:36:03.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCPvyOQD9hxY8433PN9QalIg",
    "title": "CALIFORNIA ADVENTURE",
    "description": "Day 1 of my California/Vidcon vlogs\n\nNext vlog - http://youtu.be/4J8wUIK-bzM\nLast vlog - http://youtu.be/7DyTydTCMJU\nKenny's collab - http://youtu.be/ATEu1Tk2pys\n\nYouTubers in the video!\nhttps://www.youtube.com/PointlessBlog\nhttps://www.youtube.com/callux\nhttps://www.youtube.com/jeffreyfever\nhttps://www.youtube.com/edsta\nhttps://www.youtube.com/iamKennyBrown\nhttps://www.youtube.com/sxephil\nhttps://www.youtube.com/TheOliWhiteTV\nhttps://www.youtube.com/jameschats\nhttps://www.youtube.com/benwillingdorf\nhttps://www.youtube.com/panopancakes\nhttps://www.youtube.com/tayzonday\nhttps://www.youtube.com/wtffilmsftw\nhttps://www.youtube.com/mysteryguitarman\nhttps://www.youtube.com/mikeybolts\n\n\nMain Channel - http://youtube.com/motokimaxted\nTwitter - http://twitter.com/motokimaxted\nInstagram - http://instagr.am/motokimaxted\nFacebook - http://facebook.com/motokimaxted\nTumblr - http://motokimaxted.tumblr.com\nVine - https://vine.co/motokimaxted\n\nSpecial thanks to the music with sick summer vibes by:\nhttps://soundcloud.com/thecancel\nhttps://soundcloud.com/thebeatknitter\nhttps://soundcloud.com/whoisqueen",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/H4yPmh2C_08/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
```

So my question is: how can i get a list of videos simply by having a subscription ID? or at least I would like to know what is the formula youtube uses to retrieve the *default* list of videos under a subscription?

Comment: I can't find anything in the documentation about directly associating a subscription with the specified channel's uploaded videos, so I'm inclined to believe the way you described is the way Youtube gets the videos for your subscriptions. It would be nice if they could include that channel's upload playlist ID in the resourceID, maybe you could file a feature request for it.

Comment: @not_a_bot turns out we can use search.. see [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32242178/766570) below

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that there is an easier path.. after retrieving the channelId from the user subscriptions call (see part 1 in question above.. the channel id is **UCPvyOQD9hxY8433PN9QalIg**) we can use this as a **channelID** parameter in the [youtube search api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) (and aldo adding *snippet* as a **part** parameter).. the result looks like this:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/dhO9gkvzsSRnS_UX-4W-XrFxiPc\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 27,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/_11G-M9NjTm9Sc-HOgRE7MjzVJU\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "Nx1a1aTcSGk"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-06-02T02:40:52.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCPvyOQD9hxY8433PN9QalIg",
    "title": "Songs in Real Life Spring Edition",
    "description": "High school students live their lives singing modern hit songs. Watch the first one - https://youtu.be/LRPUtpiKnKU Snapchat - MotokiMaxted Main ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Nx1a1aTcSGk/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Nx1a1aTcSGk/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Nx1a1aTcSGk/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "moretoki",
    "liveBroadcastCo
    ...
```